# How to find the explicit solution of $y'(x)= |y(x)|(1-y(x)) \frac{x^3}{1+x^4}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Given,
$$y'(x)= |y(x)|(1-y(x)) \frac{x^3}{1+x^4}$$ with initial conditions $y(0) = 2$

I know that the y(x) can be found using Bernoulli's method such that

$$\frac{y'}{y^2} -\frac{x^3}{y(1+x^4)} = -\frac{x^3}{1+x^4} $$

Assuming $\frac{1}{y} = v$

Thus,

$$I.F ={\mathrm e}^{\int_0^x\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}} dx$$
or,$$ I.F. = (1+x^4)^\frac{1}{4} $$

Thus,
$$ \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{y} =\int_0^x {\frac{x^3(1+x^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{1+x^4}} dx $$

and this is where I got stuck. How shall I proceed from here?

Somehow the answer is $$y(x) = \frac {(2^4)\sqrt{1+x^4}}{-1 + 2(1+x^4)^{\frac{1}4}}$$

I also observe that this can be solved using the separable variable method but I still have trouble getting to the answer. I will be grateful if anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Check the reference solution if the numerator is not $2\,\sqrt[4\;]{1+x^4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $(1+x^4)^{1/4}$ is $x^3(1+x^4)^{-3/4}$, which is exactly the integrand you are in doubt of.

---

The equation is separable, so a better substitution would use and preserve that pattern by setting $v=y^{-1}-1$. Then
$$
v'=-y^{-2}y'=-sv\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}, ~~~ s=sign(y(0)).
$$
This is obviously again separable
$$
\ln(v)=\frac{-s}4\ln(1+x^4)+c
\\
v=C(1+x^4)^{-s/4}
$$
etc.